# Сортировка многомерного массива в Laravel

Tags: php, массивы, laravel

Есть многомерный массив:

```
$filter = [
        'trainer' => \Input::get('trainer', null),
        'group' => \Input::get('group', null)
    ];

    $club_id = 1;
    $data = [];
    for ( $i = 0; $i <= 12; $i++ ) {

        $row = null;
        $row = Row::whereRaw( 'club_id = ' . $club_id . ' and row_weight = ' . $i )->first();
        if ($row) {
            $columns = Column::whereRaw( 'row_id = ' . $row->id )->get();
            $rowExit = $this->formStubRow();

            foreach ( $columns as $column ) {
                $time = $column->time;
                $gym = $column->gym;
                $status = $column->status;
                $worker_name = Worker::find( $column->worker_id )->worker_name;
                $service_title = Service::find( $column->service_id )->service_title;
                $rowExit[ $column->day ][ $gym ] = [ ];

                if( ( $filter[ 'trainer' ] != null && $worker_name == $filter[ 'trainer' ] ) ||
                    ( $filter[ 'group' ] != null && $service_title == $filter[ 'group' ] ) ||
                    ( $filter[ 'trainer' ] == null && $filter[ 'group' ] == null )
                ){
                    $rowExit[ $column->day ][ $gym ] = [
                        'time'      => $time,
                        'gym'       => $gym,
                        'group'     => $service_title,
                        'trainer'   => $worker_name,
                        'status'    => $status,
                        'activate'  => true
                    ];

                }
            }
            array_push( $data, $rowExit );
        } else {
            array_push( $data, $this->formStubRow() );
        }
        Log::debug('WTF IS THIS THEN?!!: '.print_r($filter['group'], true));
    }
    return view('pages.services.indexTimetable', compact('filter'),  [ 'data' => $data ] );
}
```

Исходя из него выведена таблица, но вот как подобраться к редактированию объекта и как вывести данные 'trainer' и 'group' в select'ы, никак не могу придумать.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно подставить переменные, чтобы вывести в select названия групп и имена тренеров?

view-файл расписания:

```
@extends('basic.main')
@section('page_title')

Расписание групповых программ

@stop
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="text-about">
                <h3 class="about-title">РАСПИСАНИЕ ГРУППОВЫХ ПРОГРАММ</h3>
            </div>
            {!! Form::open(['class' => 'form-inline', 'method' => 'get', 'route' => ['timetable-show']]) !!}
            <div id="group-select" class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('filter', ' ', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}<br>
                {!! Form::select('filter',  $filter, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
            </div>
            <div id="trainer-select" class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('filter', ' ', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
            {!! Form::select('filter', $filter, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
            </div>
            {!! Form::submit('применить', ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) !!}
            {!! Form::close() !!}



            <div id="table-shedule">
                <div id="time-days" class='row' style='clear:both;width:1190px;'>
                    <div id="shedule-day" class='cell'
                         style='width:169px;float:left;text-align: center;min-height:20px;'>
                        <p>{{ 'Пн' }}</p>
                    </div>

                    <div id="shedule-day" class='cell'
                         style='width:169px;float:left;text-align: center;min-height:20px;'>
                        <p>{{ 'Вт' }}</p>
                    </div>

                    <div id="shedule-day" class='cell'
                         style='width:169px;float:left;text-align: center;min-height:20px;'>
                        <p>{{ 'Ср' }}</p>
                    </div>

                    <div id="shedule-day" class='cell'
                         style='width:169px;float:left;text-align: center;min-height:20px;'>
                        <p>{{ 'Чт' }}</p>
                    </div>

                    <div id="shedule-day" class='cell'
                         style='width:169px;float:left;text-align: center;min-height:20px;'>
                        <p>{{ 'Пт' }}</p>
                    </div>

                    <div id="shedule-day" class='cell'
                         style='width:169px;float:left;text-align: center;min-height:20px;'>
                        <p>{{ 'Сб' }}</p>
                    </div>

                    <div id="shedule-day" class='cell'
                         style='width:169px;float:left;text-align: center;min-height:20px;'>
                        <p>{{ 'Вс' }}</p>
                    </div>

                </div>
                @foreach( $data as $row )
                    <div class='row' style='clear:both;width:1200px;'>
                        @foreach( $row as $day=>$gymArray )
                            <div class='cell'
                                 style='width:170px;float:left;;text-align: center;max-height:370px;overflow: auto'>
                                @foreach( $gymArray as $gym=>$gymInfo )
                                    <div class='gym' style='clear:both'>
                                        <p>{{ $gymInfo[ 'time' ] or '' }}</p><hr id="hr-time" style="width:20%"/>
                                        <strong id="group-name">{{ $gymInfo[ 'group' ] or '' }}</strong><br>
                                        {{ $gymInfo[ 'trainer' ] or '' }}<br>
                                        <small id="gym-name">{{ $gym or '' }}</small><br>
                                        {{ $gymInfo[ 'status' ] or '' }}
                                    </div>
                                @endforeach
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@stop
```

Comment: Как выглядит таблица в итоговом варианте? К редактированию какого объекта вы хотите подобраться? В какие селекты вы хотите вывести данные? Где эти селекты? Как выглядят модели для используемых сущностей? Какие поля в задействованных таблицах?

Comment: @VenZell добавил view код таблицы, при сортировке селектом будут подсвечиваться подходящие columns с данными о тренере группе и зале, редактирование следовательно этих же параметров у columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача решилась таким образом:
Массив:

```
public function index()
{
    $trainers = Worker::all()->toArray();
    $trainersArray = [  'all' => 'все тренеры' ];
    foreach( $trainers as $trainer ){
    $trainersArray[ $trainer[ 'id'] ] = $trainer[ 'worker_name' ];
    }

    $groups = Service::all()->toArray();
    $groupsArray = [  'all' => 'все группы' ];
    foreach( $groups as $group ){
    $groupsArray [ $group[ 'id'] ] = $group[ 'service_title' ];}

    $filter = [

        'trainer' => \Input::get( 'trainer',  null ),
        'group' => \Input::get( 'group',  null )
    ];

    $club_id = 1;
    $data = [];
    for ( $i = 0; $i <= 12; $i++ ) {

        $row = null;
        $row = Row::whereRaw( 'club_id = ' . $club_id . ' and row_weight = ' . $i )->first();
        if ($row) {
            $columns = Column::whereRaw( 'row_id = ' . $row->id )->get();
            $rowExit = $this->formStubRow();

            foreach ( $columns as $column ) {
                $time = $column->time;
                $gym = $column->gym;
                $status = $column->status;
                $worker_name = Worker::find( $column->worker_id )->worker_name;
                $service_title = Service::find( $column->service_id )->service_title;
                $rowExit[ $column->day ][ $gym ] = [ ];

                $errors = false;
                if( $filter[ 'trainer' ] != null  && ( $filter[ 'trainer' ] != 'all' && $column->worker_id != $filter[ 'trainer' ] ) ){
                    $errors = true;
                }

                if( $filter[ 'group' ] != null  && ( $filter[ 'group' ] != 'all' && $column->service_id != $filter[ 'group' ] ) ){
                    $errors = true;
                }

                if( !$errors ){
                    $rowExit[ $column->day ][ $gym ] = [
                        'time'      => $time,
                        'gym'       => $gym,
                        'group'     => $service_title,
                        'trainer'   => $worker_name,
                        'status'    => $status,
                        'activate'  => true
                    ];
                }
            }
            array_push( $data, $rowExit );
        } else {
                array_push($data, $this->formStubRow());
            }
        }
    return view('pages.services.indexTimetable', [ 'data' => $data, 'filter' => $filter,  'groups' => $groupsArray, 'trainers' => $trainersArray ] );
}
```

View:

```
{!! Form::open(['class' => 'form-inline', 'method' => 'get', 'route' => ['timetable-show']]) !!}
        <div id="trainer-select" class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('group', ' ', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
            {!! Form::select('group', $groups, null,  ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>
        <div id="group-select" class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('trainer', ' ', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}<br>
            {!! Form::select('trainer', $trainers, null,  ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>
        {!! Form::submit('применить', ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) !!}
        {!! Form::close() !!}
```